# Problems displaying actions in a listing table

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I have a problem in the column referring to the column **Actions** of my listings table. The error is as follows.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "<" in C:\xampp\htdocs\mangas\view\form_select_manga.php on line 42`
```

This error is caused by:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" title="Edit" href="edit_manga.php?id_manga=<?php echo $id_manga ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" href="delete_manga.php?id_manga=<?php echo $id_manga ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
```

Only the two action buttons have this problem, I have difficulties to adapt the table without causing an error.

```
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <h4 class="text-center">Manga list</h4>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Publisher</th>
                    <th>Volumes</th>
                    <th>Discont</th>
                    <th>Collection value</th>
                    <th>Registration date</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    require_once "../model/MangaDAO.php";
                    $manga = new MangaDAO();
                    foreach ($manga->selectAllMangas() as $value){
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td title="'.$value['id_manga'].'">'.$value['id_manga'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td title="'.$value['title'].'">'.$value['title'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td title="'.$value['publisher'].'">'.$value['publisher'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td title="'.$value['volumes'].'">'.$value['volumes'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td title="R$'.$value['discont'].'">R$'.$value['discont'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td title="R$'.$value['value'].'">R$'.$value['value'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td title="'.date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($value['registration_date'])).'">'.
                        date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($value['registration_date'])).'</td>';
                        <a class="btn btn-info" title="Edit" href="edit_manga.php?id_manga=<?php echo $id_manga ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" href="delete_manga.php?id_manga=<?php echo $id_manga ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
                        echo '</tr>'; echo '</p>';
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: (a) Did you forget enclosing the HTML contents in `echo` statements ? (b) Should `<?php echo $id_manga ?>` be `<?php echo $value['id_manga']; ?>` ?

Comment: Are there <?php?> in <?php?>  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    require_once "../model/MangaDAO.php";
    $manga = new MangaDAO();
    foreach ($manga->readAllMangas() as $value){
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td title="'.$value['id_manga'].'">'.$value['id_manga'].'</td>';
            echo '<td title="'.$value['title].'">'.$value['title'].'</td>';
            echo '<td title="'.$value['publisher'].'">'.$value['publisher'].'</td>';
            echo '<td title="'.$value['volumes'].'">'.$value['volumes'].'</td>';
            echo '<td title="R$'.$value['discount'].'">R$'.$value['discount'].'</td>';
            echo '<td title="R$'.$value['value'].'">R$'.$value['value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td title="'.date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($value['registering_date'])).'">'.
            date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($value['registering_date'])).'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo '<a class="btn btn-info" title="Update '.$value['title'].'"'.'href="/mangas/view/form_update_manga.php?id_manga='.$value['id_manga'].'"role="button" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Update</a>';
                echo "&nbsp;";
                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete '.$value['title'].'"'.'href="/mangas/controller/delete_manga.php?id_manga='.$value['id_manga'].'"role="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>';
            echo '</td>';                  
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }
?>
```